# Composite with smart pointers without dynamic_pointer_cast

Tags: c++, design-patterns, c++11, composite

I implemented the composite pattern using smart pointers, it works until a point.

The problem is that I just can use the methods that is implemented in the interface and I can not use the methods that is defined in the derived class without using `dynamic_pointer_cast` and I don't want it.

I want to know if it's possible to do it without using `dynamic_pointer_cast`.

I heard that I need to implement the visitor pattern, but I really don't know how to and if it fits in that problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Fruit
{
public:
    virtual void getOld() = 0;
};

class Orange : Fruit
{
public:
    Orange() {}

    void add(std::shared_ptr<Fruit> f)
    {
        v.push_back(f);
    }

    std::shared_ptr<Fruit> get(int k)
    {
        return v[k];
    }

    void getOld()
    {
        std::cout << "Orange - I'm old." << std::endl;
    }
private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Fruit>> v;
};

class Bitter : public Fruit
{
public:
    Bitter() {}

    void getOld()
    {
        std::cout << "Bitter - I'm old." << std::endl;
    }

    void getNew()
    {
        std::cout << "Bitter - I'm new." << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    auto orange = new Orange;
    orange->add(std::make_shared<Bitter>());
    auto bitter = orange->get(0);
    bitter->getOld();

    return 0;
}
```

It works as you can see here on the [live preview](https://ideone.com/Lajcid), but when I try to use:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    auto orange = new Orange;
    orange->add(std::make_shared<Bitter>());
    auto bitter = orange->get(0);
    bitter->getOld();
    bitter->getNew();

    return 0;
}
```

I got errors:

> error: 'class Fruit' has no member named 'getNew'

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here I think is that it would work with polymorphism but the method 'getNew' doesn't exist in the mother class so you need to define it and make it virtual. It's the only way to do it without using a cast on the object.
With this line it should work.

```
virtual void getNew() = 0;
```

Comment: I know it, but what happen if I have dozens of classes with different methods? The interface will be a mess with a lot of methods, don't you think? - Let's wait in order to see if someone has a solution or at least a way to make this better. Thanks.

Comment: The problem might be your design then. If you know what type Orange will return then you can make functions like 'getBitter' instead of just 'get'

Comment: Again the same issue, what happen if I have dozens of classes? I will need to create methods to each one. If we look at implementation side we can do it, but what about the API?

Comment: It's one of the flaws of C++ and Java and you need to make it with a cast or use polymorphism. Once you put a derivate type in a generic one you lose the information about the type itself. The only way to use the specific part of the object is to cast it (which is unsafe, hence why your solution is probably a bad design)

Comment: Why it's unsafe? And you think that the best way is to define the methods in the base class or define a method to get each class that I have?

Comment: A cast is always unsafe. In this case you know the object is of the right type but using a cast is an ugly way to get around type safety. If you tried to do it with something that doesn't have the right type you'd get an exception at runtime. The whole point of using a language with static typing is to have type safety to theoretically remove runtime errors. If you cast the types you defeat the whole point of it.

Comment: The best way would be to think the design differently, a good design (especially for an API) should not require casting stuff.

Comment: And which design you think that would be better in this case? - The idea is (similar) to the composite pattern, how can I make a kind of container using a different design?

Comment: Note: it's not because some patterns are in books that they are good. I'm not sure what you're exactly trying to do but in the end if you have only one vector/list of the parent object where you want to put the more specific objects you're going either to cast them or to rely on polymorphism (or use some way around without explicitly casting which is even worse)

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to have the following function in `Orange`.

```
template <typename T>
T* get(int k)
{
    return dynamic_cast<T*>(v[k].get());
}
```

And then use:

```
auto bitter = orange->get<Bitter>(0);
bitter->getOld();
bitter->getNew();
```

This performs a `dynamic_cast` but is localized to `Orange`.

Comment: you're just hiding the cast here though. You're just moving the problem.

Comment: @meneldal, no argument there. Just providing a mechanism to reduce the spread of `dynamic_cast` to other functions.

Answer (score 1):

Following information can be found about "***composite pattern***" from the [GOF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) book. Of course it has been explained based on graphics class.

The ***key*** to the Composite pattern is ***an abstract class*** that ***represents*** ***both*** ***primitives*** and ***their containers***. For the graphics system, this class is Graphic. Graphic declares operations like ***Draw*** that are specific to graphical objects. It ***also*** declares operations that ***all composite objects share***, such as operations for accessing and managing its children.

Based on the above explanation,we should ideally declare all possible interfaces of leaf and non-leaf(container) type of node while using composite pattern.I think that this is essential in order to let client treating individual objects and compositions of objects uniformly. So ideally you should declare your classes in the following way while using this particular pattern. Any logic which has been written based on the exact type of object in the client code violates the essence of this pattern.

```
//Abstract class which should have all the interface common to
// Composite and Leaf class. It may also provide the default 
// implementation wherever appropriate.
class Fruit {
public:
    virtual void getOld() = 0;
    virtual void getNew() = 0;
    virtual void add(std::shared_ptr<Fruit> f) { }
    virtual  std::shared_ptr<Fruit> get(int index ) {return nullptr; }
    virtual ~Fruit() { }
};


//Composite Node
class Orange : Fruit {
public:
    Orange() {}
    void add(std::shared_ptr<Fruit> f) { v.push_back(f); }
    std::shared_ptr<Fruit> get(int k) { return v[k]; }
    void getOld()  { std::cout << "Orange - I'm old." << std::endl; }
    void getNew() { std::cout << "Orange - I'm new." << std::endl; } 
private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Fruit>> v;
};


//Leaf node
class Bitter : public Fruit {
public:
    Bitter() {}
    void getOld() { std::cout << "Bitter - I'm old." << std::endl; }
    void getNew() { std::cout << "Bitter - I'm new." << std::endl; }
};
```